# Combine two C++ projects

Tags: c++, open-source

I am writing NoSQL database.

Everything is in 'flat' directory, containing `Makefile`, `*.h` and `*.cc` files.

I use lots of C++ templates, so I have lots of code in some of the header files.

For simplicity I separated the project to two parts.

Data storage part:
https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM3

and network part:
https://github.com/nmmmnu/asyncore_cpp

I have few general purpose files, they are currently in each of the directories.

Now I need to combine them in single project.

Because of the c++ templates, most of the code is quite interconnected, but if I put everything in single flat directory, will not look that nice for sure.

Any suggestions what directory structure I can use or how I can do the merge of the projects?

If anything is unclear, please comment, so I can improve the question.

Comment: What _is_ the question? How to structure a software project? A little broad and subjective, no?

Answer (score 1):

My rules are the following :

- Put A and B in the same directory when A uses B and B uses A
- Create a hierarchy of directories D1, D2, D3,...
- If B in Dy uses A in Dx, then x < y
- Never have two files with the same name, even in separated directories

The main reason to do that is to be able to compile an intermediate static libraries for each directory without having linking problems.

Example of directories in one of my big applications :

- BuildInfo : some tools to get info from the build (libs and compiler version, build macros, ...)
- Exceptions : All the exceptions I can use in my application
- Tools : General C++ tools like matrices, io-tools (logs, thread manager, python interface, ...)
- MyAppCommon : Common classes for my application
- Algorithms : Algorithms of my application
- Main : different main to create the final executable, libs, Python interface,...

Comment: A uses template clases from B, B do not use A. what is the purpose for D1, D2, D3,...

Comment: If you think A and B live in the same world, keep them in the same directory. If not, B can be in D1 and A in D2. I edited the answer with an example.